# Should answers promoting a petition be flagged/deleted?

Tags: discussion, flagging, answers

The following answer was posted as an answer to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/124937/iphone-4s-grayed-out-wi-fi-and-bug-report-exists-for-it):

```
This is an old problem, that Apple doesn't really care about. So sadly, we need to make
some noise to be listened and have our problems solved. This is a petition, please read
before sign it: 
[Petition][1]
Yours sincerely.

  [1]: http://www.change.org/petitions/apple-to-get-apple-to-replace-all-units-affected-
negatively-by-the-update-of-ios7-or-patch-an-update-that-will-remedy-the-issues-many-
loyal-customers-are-experiencing?share_id=EWvbUpSNtW&utm_campaign=mailto_link&utm_medium=
email&utm_source=share_petition
```

Are answers such as this worthy of being flagged NAA and deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say the mentioning of a petition isn't the reason to delete a post. It's when there's no answer to be seen and all the post does is petition / advertise. Just like spam solicitations are out of bounds, spam solicitations are similarly not primarily in the interest of collecting knowledge and solving an issue as opposed to raising awareness of a project, effort or tool.

I would say a post like that clearly could be edited into shape, so a down vote, a comment, an edit would all be great initial actions rather than needing a moderator to step in and delete. *(However, no one is under obligation to step in and save a post that could be saved, just pointing out the possibility.)*

Of course we can and should delete posts that clearly are not an answer as the linked item as posted is. I also wanted to encourage people to try to save posts by new users rather than just writing them off for deletion rather than exhausting the normal means to moderate a post.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't answer the question so flagging/deleting definitively is in order. In this case it does have some merits as a comment.